# How to detect if API is down?

Tags: facebook, button, error-handling, facebook-like

As I type this the fb:like button is down - the Facebook API health page is reporting errors
https://developers.facebook.com/live_status

I am sure it will be back soon, but how can I detect this?
The reason being; I wish to hide other elements on the page as it looks odd when you have a facebook feature & then the button is missing.

Answer (score 4):

Get the JSON response from this site: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/api_status.php

Comment: I'm sorry to be dense but how would you snag the JSON from this page because I'm having zero luck with `file_get_contents`, it returns null for me after I try to `json_decode` it.

Comment: Depends on the language. I would ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

**For NodeJS:**

You can use the https module that comes with Node: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

I was struggling with this on my Node.js server, but found a solution.  I was trying to do an http request with no luck (kept getting an unsupported browser problem), but when I tried to do it with cURL, it worked just fine.

So I decided to pass a User-Agent in my header for my NodeJS request, since I was getting that unsupported browser problem:

```js
var https = require("https");

var options = {
      hostname: 'www.facebook.com',
      port: 443,
      path: '/feeds/api_status.php',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        "User-Agent": 'curl/7.43.0'
      }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function(d) {
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });
});

req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

The api_status then prints out in your console as so:

```
{
   "current": {
      "health": 1,
      "subject": "Facebook Platform is Healthy"
    },
    "push": {
       "status": "Complete",
       "updated": "2016-01-27T16:05:12-08:00",
       "id": 61183893
    }
}
```

You can do what you need with it.  For example, if you want to use it to see if the Facebook API is healthy, you can do the following:

```js
var facebookIsHealthy;

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
   res.on('data', function(d) {
      // d is a buffer object

      var bufferString = d.toString();
      var bufferObject = JSON.parse(bufferString);

      if(bufferObject.current.health === 1) {
          facebookIsHealthy = true;
      }

      else {
          facebookIsHealthy = false;
      }
   });
});
```

Hope this helps!